# AcademicPaperPros - Question regarding writing

Tags: node.js

I am looking for a solution to write to a file while using Node.js. So far no success. Any suggestions or feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you searched on? What have you tried? Node does file reading and writing with the fs module.

Comment: Did you even google? There is even a dedicated tutorial on the official website. [How do I write files in Node.js?](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/file-system/how-to-write-files-in-nodejs/) If you encounter any issue with your code, make sure to include your code in the post and also include the error message if you are getting some.